# Is it possible in C# to declare a delegate type in which the input parameters are dynamic but the return type is not?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, .net-6.0, anonymous-methods

I am in .NET 6.0. I have a class, we'll call him "ComplexObject". ComplexObject has some complex/dynamic data structures under the hood [that aren't relevant to the question], and the best way we found to consume some of this data from a different class is with a caller-specified `Delegate`. So the ComplexObject class has a method that currently looks like this (simplified for clarity):

```
public T Evaluate<T>(Delegate method)
{
    var parameters = DoMagicToGetTheParameterValues(method);
    var obj = method.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
    return CustomConvertTo<T>(obj);
}
```

This method gives the caller the ability to do something like this:

```
{
    var instance = GetComplexObject();
    var name = instance.Evaluate<string>((SimpleEntity simple) => {
        return simple.Name ?? simple.ToString();
    });
    var result = SomeMethodThatNeedsANameParameter(name);
    return result;
}
```

This code works as intended, but because of the vanilla `Delegate` argument type, it cannot infer the return type, enforce a return statement in general, or receive any benefits that generics give you in .NET.

Is there a way in C# to create a delegate type that enforces a specified result type but does not restrict the input arguments?

TLDR; is this possible in .NET?

`public Delegate T EvaluationDelegate<T>(/* ANY number of parameters of ANY type in ANY order from ANY caller */);`

I tried a bunch of different combinations of delegate declarations and none of them worked. I know there is a solution that looks something like this:

```
public TResult Evaluate<TArg1, TResult>(Func<TArg1, TResult> method);
public TResult Evaluate<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult> method);
public TResult Evaluate<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TResult>(Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TResult> method);
...etc, keep going until I deem necessary
```

But even then, there's an issue in .NET 6. The syntax in the caller, where the input arguments are specified this way:

```
var name = instance.Evaluate<string>((SimpleEntity simple) => {
    return simple.Name ?? simple.ToString();
});

var name = instance.Evaluate<string>((SimpleEntity simple, MediumEntity medium) => {
    return simple.Name ?? medium.Name ?? simple.ToString();
});
```

Anything beyond one input argument seems to run into the
`incompatible anonymous function signature` when the method names match, and the
`Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage` error when the method names differ (I would rather them match). At that point, I'd rather just trust the caller then force them to actually type out the generic arguments...

This may be this is possible in .NET 7.0 or .NET 8.0, I have not tried in either of those versions of .NET. Nonetheless, the focus of the question is above - if it possible to accomplish this goal with a *delegate type*.

Thank you in advance for anyone who took the time to read/respond to my question!

Comment: Could you use closures? You could have different 'factory' methods that all produce a `Func<TResult>`. Instead of the delegate accepting parameters, the values are captured in a closure (i.e. "outer variables") when the `Func<TResult>` is created in the factory method.

Comment: Can't reproduce this : "beyond one input argument seems to run into the incompatible anonymous function signature". Could you please update the question with complete code snippet - you're specifying just one generic type explicitly "Evaluate<string>" which won't compile?

Comment: @Serg Good catch! I think it does actually, don't know how I missed that one hahaha. Unfortunately, I think the first answer confirms my suspicions that I can't really achieve exactly what I'm looking for :( And Jon Skeet's answer doesn't do anything for me because in his examples, the caller has the values. In my scenario, the values are not known [anywhere public] until the delegate is ready to be dynamically invoked. I'll keep trying, but I will likely make the answer to this question in which there is not an answer hahaha. Thank you good sir :)

Comment: @JonathanDodds Hmmm, maybe like a generic class [in which the generic type parameters become the Delegate parameter types] and it has a method to call into the ComplexObject instance internally with those parameter types and that should in fact enforce a result of the same type via another class that carries the result T type through. Sounds like a pain since it would still result in a bunch of boilerplate to have different classes for each number of parameters (like the Func example above) and would have rigid parameter names, but that is an interesting idea. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @EdgarsPivovarenoks Hello! If you referring to the last snippet I have in there, try it while it's pointing to an interface method that looks like the first one (with the Delegate parameter). That *should* compile/work. If not, I likely just made a silly mistake typing it out in the question hahaha. Hopefully something easy if that's the case. Then once that is good, change the interface method to do it the Func<> way. That is essentially how I got those two errors. Don't kill yourself over this man, it's not looking like a delegate type is the answer here - but thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: @Donald.Record legitimately want to help, as functional aspect of c# is my cup of tea. :)

Comment: @Donald.Record this seems to blend :

https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zk89zsv2AP

Feel free to adjust to reflect your situation.

Comment: Not classes with generic types. I was thinking you could have methods with very different parameters but all returning a `Func<object>` that has a closure on the parameters of the creating method. The differences in the parameters and the differences in handling those parameters are encapsulated inside the function object. In `T Evaluate<T>(Func<object> method)` the `DoMagicToGetTheParameterValues` is eliminated. The passed in `Func<object>` can just be executed, e.g. `var obj = method();`.

Comment: @EdgarsPivovarenoks There is a dialog that says "Join Session" and any answer to that dialog doesn't seem to divert away from the default "Hello World". Sorry, wish I had more for you, but I have zero experience with DotNetFiddle.